# How to assign an instance of an object to a pointer that was null?

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, null

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
    public:
        Node *next;
        int value;
        Node(int value) {
            this->next = nullptr;
            this->value = value;
        }
};

class LinkedList {
    private:
        Node *head;
        Node *tail;
    public:
    LinkedList() {
        this->head = nullptr;
        this->tail = nullptr;
    }

    void addToEnd(int value) {
        if(head == nullptr)
            this->head = new Node(value);
        else
            this->tail->next = new Node(value);
        this->tail = this->tail->next;
    }

    void print() {
        for(Node *n = this->head; n != nullptr; n = n->next)
            cout<<n->value<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    LinkedList *list = new LinkedList();

    list->addToEnd(21);
    list->addToEnd(25);
    list->addToEnd(56);
    list->addToEnd(24);
    list->print();

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is, when I am assigning an instance of `Node` to `this->head`, the program crashes. Is there different way of assigning an instance to a pointer that was initially `nullptr`?

This code structure works fine on Java, I came from Java, that is why I have difficulty on C++'s pointers.

**EDIT**

I pasted the right code now, I'm sure. Sorry.

Ok, I have solved the problem. So, the problem is not about allocating an object to a class member, but, the problem is accessing a `nullptr` member: `this->tail`.

I edited this method, and the program now runs the way I wanted.

```
void addToEnd(int value) {
    Node *n = new Node(value);
    if(head == nullptr)
        this->head = n;
    else
        this->tail->next = n;
    this->tail = n;
}
```

Thanks for your help people, this question is now SOLVED. :)

Comment: You are attempting to assign a `Node` object to a pointer to `Node`: `this->head = Node(value);`. This shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Does it even compile? eg `this->head = Node(value);` when head is a pointer....

Comment: By "crash" do you mean you get a compiler error?

Comment: Yes, it compiles (and executes the EXE file), and the program crashes on the `this->head = new Node(value);` line.

Comment: @KaNa0011: Except that line does not exist.

Comment: Oops, I pasted the wrong code. It has a `new` keyword on those lines.

Comment: You cannot assume that a Java program will convert to C++ without change. There is a paradigm shift - memory handling is totally different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about "it crashes", but the following line is not valid:

```
this->head = Node(value);
```

`head` is a pointer-to-`Node` but you're trying to assign a `Node` to it. Even if this automatically took the address of the temporary you created on the RHS (which it doesn't), you'd have a pointer to a local variable that doesn't exist for very long.

You should be getting a compilation error for that.

You'd have to use `new` to create a new object dynamically — be sure to write code to free that memory later!

You're similarly messing up dynamic memory allocation in `main`, where you have a needless memory leak. `LinkedList list;` will do fine, there.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now.

So, I must assign a `Node` pointer to `this->head`. It not possible to assign by using `*(new Node(value))` (I just guessed that :p)
I am thinking of using `malloc` function. Will the program behave similarly if i used `malloc` instead of `new`?
Btw, objects are references right? Just like in Java?

Comment: You would assign `new Node(value)`. No idea why you tried to dereference it just then! Don't fallback on `malloc` just because you got `new` syntax wrong. And, no, objects are objects, and references are references. Stop thinking of Java, completely. Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: Ok, I tried the `new Node(value)` code. It still crashes.
I will remember the difference of objects and references and C++ and Java :)

Also, I'm not using any books. Just translating my Java into C++, with my minimal C++ knowledge.

Comment: @KaNa0011: Then spend some time with your debugger! Or even paper. Track the steps of your program. Inspect values. Rationalise.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider `std::unique_ptr<Node>`. Coming from a Java background, you'll appreciate smart pointers which clean up after themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for your `Node` instances. The quickest way is to call `new Node(value)` wherever you call `Node(value)`. However if I were you I'd consider using `shared_ptr<Node>` rather than plain pointers.